# Adding list of values to a list of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two list, one list containing dictionaries, the other list values.

```
l_dic = [
  {
    'a': 5,
    'b': 7,
    'c': [1,2,3,4,5]
  },
  {
    'a': 12,
    'b': 4,
    'c': [1,2,3,4,5]
  }
]

val = [458,646]
```

Now I'm trying to add the values to the dictionaries, so the result is looking like this:

```
res_dic = [
  {
    'a': 5,
    'b': 7,
    'c': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'd': 458
  },
  {
    'a': 12,
    'b': 4,
    'c': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'd': 646
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use python built-in function `zip` with list comprehension

```
l_dic = [{**d, 'd': e} for d, e in zip(l_dic, val)]
```

**output:**

```
[
  {
    "a": 5,
    "b": 7,
    "c": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "d": 458
  },
  {
    "a": 12,
    "b": 4,
    "c": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "d": 646
  }
]
```

or you can use a for loop:

```
for d, v in zip(l_dic, val):
    d['d'] = v
```

here is a benchmark of the proposed solutions:

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder
b = BenchmarkBuilder()



@b.add_function()
def kederrac_for_loop(args):
    l_dic, val = args
    for d, v in zip(l_dic, val):
        d['d'] = v


@b.add_function()
def kederrac_list_comprehension(args):
    l_dic, val = args
    l_dic = [{**d, 'd': e} for d, e in zip(l_dic, val)]

@b.add_function()
def GoodDeeds_for_loop(args):
    l_dic, val = args
    for i in range(len(val)):
        l_dic[i]['d'] = val[i]

@b.add_function()        
def Nizam_solution(args)    : 
    l_dic, val = args
    def assign(x):
        l_dic[x]['d'] = val[x]

    #runs paralelly utilizing all cores on your machine
    ignore_this = [*map(lambda x: assign(x),range(len(l_dic)))]

@b.add_arguments('Number of elements')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(2, 16):
        size = 2**exp
        l_dic = [{i : choice(range(100)) for i in range(choice(range(3, 100)))} for _ in range(size)]
        val = list(range(size))

        yield size, (l_dic, val)

r = b.run()
r.plot()
```

output:

[image]

as you can see the for loop solution is the fastest one

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a loop:

```
for i in range(len(val)):
    res_dic[i]['d'] = val[i]
```

assuming `res_dic` and `val` are lists of the same length.

Comment: I was hoping, there is a more efficient way to do this, because I have a lot of data.

Comment: @WhiteWolf If efficiency was important then you should have said so in the question; nobody is going to guess your requirements if you don't write them. But you cannot really do it more efficiently than this, except for micro-optimisations; fundamentally you want to update that many dictionaries, so you have to update that many dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `map` function which takes a function and an iterable as arguments and applies the function to each element in the iterable parallelly utilizing all the cores on your machine

```
l_dic = [
  {
    'a': 5,
    'b': 7,
    'c': [1,2,3,4,5]
  },
  {
    'a': 12,
    'b': 4,
    'c': [1,2,3,4,5]
  }
]

val = [458,646]

def assign(x):
  l_dic[x]['d'] = val[x]

#runs paralelly utilizing all cores on your machine
ignore_this = [*map(lambda x: assign(x),range(len(l_dic)))]
```

Output

```
l_dic

{'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'd': 458},
 {'a': 12, 'b': 4, 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'd': 646}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a little undefined, since the exact pattern of your keys isn't really defined beyond 26 items, but with some assumptions, you can work with it. What we'll do is `zip()` your list of dictionaries and your list of items, and do the assignment on a line-by-line basis.

```py
def dict_list_apply(dict_list:list, items_list:list):

  def get_next_key(_dict):
    ab = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    return ab[len(_dict)%len(ab)] * (len(_dict)//len(ab)+1)

  for _dict, _item in zip(dict_list, items_list):
    _dict[get_next_key(_dict)] = _item
```

The above code will insert items with keys in the following pattern:

`a, b, ..., y, z, aa, bb, ..., yy, zz, aaa, bbb, ..., etc.`

This means that we can indefinitely continue to add keys to each dictionary, regardless of the length of the other dictionaries.

Then, if we run something like this:

```py
l_dic = [
  {
    'a': 5,
    'b': 7,
    'c': [1,2,3,4,5]
  },
  {
    'a': 12,
    'b': 4,
    'c': [1,2,3,4,5]
  }
]

val = [458,646]

for x in range(100):
    dict_list_apply(l_dic, map(lambda v: v + x, val))
pprint.pprint(l_dic)
```

Then we get the following output:

> ```
> [{'a': 5,
>   'aa': 481,
>   'aaa': 507,
>   'aaaa': 533,
>   'b': 7,
>   'bb': 482,
>   'bbb': 508,
>   'bbbb': 534,
>   'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
>   'cc': 483,
>   'ccc': 509,
>   'cccc': 535,
>   'd': 458,
>   'dd': 484,
>   'ddd': 510,
>   'dddd': 536,
>   'e': 459,
>   'ee': 485,
>   'eee': 511,
>   'eeee': 537,
>   'f': 460,
>   'ff': 486,
>   'fff': 512,
>   'ffff': 538,
>   'g': 461,
>   'gg': 487,
>   'ggg': 513,
>   'gggg': 539,
>   'h': 462,
>   'hh': 488,
>   'hhh': 514,
>   'hhhh': 540,
>   'i': 463,
>   'ii': 489,
>   'iii': 515,
>   'iiii': 541,
>   'j': 464,
>   'jj': 490,
>   'jjj': 516,
>   'jjjj': 542,
>   'k': 465,
>   'kk': 491,
>   'kkk': 517,
>   'kkkk': 543,
>   'l': 466,
>   'll': 492,
>   'lll': 518,
>   'llll': 544,
>   'm': 467,
>   'mm': 493,
>   'mmm': 519,
>   'mmmm': 545,
>   'n': 468,
>   'nn': 494,
>   'nnn': 520,
>   'nnnn': 546,
>   'o': 469,
>   'oo': 495,
>   'ooo': 521,
>   'oooo': 547,
>   'p': 470,
>   'pp': 496,
>   'ppp': 522,
>   'pppp': 548,
>   'q': 471,
>   'qq': 497,
>   'qqq': 523,
>   'qqqq': 549,
>   'r': 472,
>   'rr': 498,
>   'rrr': 524,
>   'rrrr': 550,
>   's': 473,
>   'ss': 499,
>   'sss': 525,
>   'ssss': 551,
>   't': 474,
>   'tt': 500,
>   'ttt': 526,
>   'tttt': 552,
>   'u': 475,
>   'uu': 501,
>   'uuu': 527,
>   'uuuu': 553,
>   'v': 476,
>   'vv': 502,
>   'vvv': 528,
>   'vvvv': 554,
>   'w': 477,
>   'ww': 503,
>   'www': 529,
>   'wwww': 555,
>   'x': 478,
>   'xx': 504,
>   'xxx': 530,
>   'xxxx': 556,
>   'y': 479,
>   'yy': 505,
>   'yyy': 531,
>   'yyyy': 557,
>   'z': 480,
>   'zz': 506,
>   'zzz': 532},
>  {'a': 12,
>   'aa': 669,
>   'aaa': 695,
>   'aaaa': 721,
>   'b': 4,
>   'bb': 670,
>   'bbb': 696,
>   'bbbb': 722,
>   'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
>   'cc': 671,
>   'ccc': 697,
>   'cccc': 723,
>   'd': 646,
>   'dd': 672,
>   'ddd': 698,
>   'dddd': 724,
>   'e': 647,
>   'ee': 673,
>   'eee': 699,
>   'eeee': 725,
>   'f': 648,
>   'ff': 674,
>   'fff': 700,
>   'ffff': 726,
>   'g': 649,
>   'gg': 675,
>   'ggg': 701,
>   'gggg': 727,
>   'h': 650,
>   'hh': 676,
>   'hhh': 702,
>   'hhhh': 728,
>   'i': 651,
>   'ii': 677,
>   'iii': 703,
>   'iiii': 729,
>   'j': 652,
>   'jj': 678,
>   'jjj': 704,
>   'jjjj': 730,
>   'k': 653,
>   'kk': 679,
>   'kkk': 705,
>   'kkkk': 731,
>   'l': 654,
>   'll': 680,
>   'lll': 706,
>   'llll': 732,
>   'm': 655,
>   'mm': 681,
>   'mmm': 707,
>   'mmmm': 733,
>   'n': 656,
>   'nn': 682,
>   'nnn': 708,
>   'nnnn': 734,
>   'o': 657,
>   'oo': 683,
>   'ooo': 709,
>   'oooo': 735,
>   'p': 658,
>   'pp': 684,
>   'ppp': 710,
>   'pppp': 736,
>   'q': 659,
>   'qq': 685,
>   'qqq': 711,
>   'qqqq': 737,
>   'r': 660,
>   'rr': 686,
>   'rrr': 712,
>   'rrrr': 738,
>   's': 661,
>   'ss': 687,
>   'sss': 713,
>   'ssss': 739,
>   't': 662,
>   'tt': 688,
>   'ttt': 714,
>   'tttt': 740,
>   'u': 663,
>   'uu': 689,
>   'uuu': 715,
>   'uuuu': 741,
>   'v': 664,
>   'vv': 690,
>   'vvv': 716,
>   'vvvv': 742,
>   'w': 665,
>   'ww': 691,
>   'www': 717,
>   'wwww': 743,
>   'x': 666,
>   'xx': 692,
>   'xxx': 718,
>   'xxxx': 744,
>   'y': 667,
>   'yy': 693,
>   'yyy': 719,
>   'yyyy': 745,
>   'z': 668,
>   'zz': 694,
>   'zzz': 720}]
> ```

Now, this isn't the only way to generate keys, so you can change that by modifying the `get_next_key` function to provide the pattern that you want.